# Support extra large screens on Android 5+ Google Play

Tags: android, google-play, tablet

I am trying to support an Android tablet app for devices like **Samsung View** and **HP Slate 17**, which have extra large screens (17"+). I have already enabled the `android:xlargeScreens='true'` in the Manifest as shown below,

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="false" android:normalScreens="false"
    android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:anyDensity="true" android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600"/>
```

but when I try to upload the app to Google Play, the devices mentioned above are grayed out.
Is there something else I need to do?

Here is the entire manifest:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<manifest package='__PACKAGE__' android:versionCode='1' android:versionName='1.00' xmlns:android='http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android'>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion='15' android:targetSdkVersion='15'/>

<supports-screens android:smallScreens="false" android:normalScreens="false"
android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true"
android:anyDensity="true" android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="320"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name='android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION' />
<uses-permission android:name='android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE'/>
<uses-permission android:name='android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE' />
<uses-permission android:name='android.permission.BLUETOOTH'/>
<uses-permission android:name='android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN'/>
<uses-permission android:name='android.permission.CAMERA'/>
<uses-permission android:name='android.permission.GET_TASKS'/>
<uses-permission android:name='android.permission.INTERNET'/>
<uses-permission android:name='android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS'/>
<uses-permission android:name='android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED'/>
<uses-permission android:name='android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO'/>
<uses-permission android:name='android.permission.WAKE_LOCK' />
<uses-permission android:name='android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'/>
<uses-permission android:name='android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS'/>

<uses-permission android:name='com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE'/>

<permission android:name='__PACKAGE__.permission.C2D_MESSAGE' android:protectionLevel='signature'/>
<uses-permission android:name='__PACKAGE__.permission.C2D_MESSAGE'/>

<uses-feature android:name='android.hardware.camera.autofocus' android:required='false'/>
<uses-feature android:name='android.hardware.microphone' android:required='false'/>
<uses-feature android:name='android.hardware.bluetooth_le' android:required='false'/>

<application android:hardwareAccelerated='true' android:icon='@drawable/ic_launcher___BRAND__' android:label='@string/app_name___BRAND__' android:largeHeap='true'>
    <meta-data android:name="brand" android:value="__BRAND__"/>
    <meta-data android:name="console_url" android:value="__CONSOLE_URL__" />

    <activity android:configChanges='orientation|screenSize' android:exported='false' android:name='org.ruboto.SplashActivity'/>

    <activity android:label='@string/app_name___BRAND__' android:name='__PACKAGE__.HomeActivity' android:enabled='false'>
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name='android.intent.action.MAIN'/>
        <category android:name='android.intent.category.HOME'/>
        <category android:name='android.intent.category.DEFAULT'/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity android:label='@string/app_name___BRAND__' android:name='__PACKAGE__.WebViewActivity' android:launchMode='singleTask' android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name='android.intent.action.MAIN'/>
    <category android:name='android.intent.category.LAUNCHER'/>
</intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity android:exported='false' android:name='org.ruboto.RubotoActivity'/>
<activity android:exported='false' android:name='org.ruboto.RubotoDialog' android:theme='@android:style/Theme.Dialog'/>
<service android:exported='false' android:name='org.ruboto.RubotoService'/>
<receiver android:name='.CloudMessageReceiver' android:permission='com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND'>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name='com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE'/>
    <category android:name='__PACKAGE__'/>
</intent-filter>
</receiver>

<receiver android:name='__PACKAGE__.OnBootReceiver'>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name='android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED'/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>


</application>
```

Thanks!

Comment: You might consider posting your entire manifest. Also, what is your `minSdkVersion`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've added the full Manifest, and my minSdkVersion is 15

Comment: Are you sure that those devices have GPS?

Comment: Samsung View definitely has GPS (http://www.samsung.com/us/support/answer/ANS00046572/) and HP Slate 17 does not.

Comment: `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` [implies that you need GPS hardware](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#permissions), so you might try adding a `<uses-feature>` element to flip that, if you do not absolutely need GPS. `<supports-screens>` is not your issue.

Comment: But how come Samsung View, which does have GPS is not supported?

Comment: It must be something else. `<supports-screens>` never filters larger sizes. It filters *smaller* sizes than you claim to support. So, if you had `<supports-screens android:smallScreens="false" android:normalScreens="true" android:largeScreens="false" android:xlargeScreens="false">`, then you would be blocked from `-small` devices, but you would be eligible for all others. In this case, the `false` for `-large` and `-xlarge` means that you did not *optimize* your app for those sizes, and Android should use pixel-doubling-ish approaches to make your UI fit the screen space.